# What is this component attached to electric pole

Tags: research

[image]I have noticed the following component attached to an electric pole, I wonder what that is.

Comment: Which component? The antenna? You should circle the object in question in photos like this.

Comment: @DKNguyen edited

Comment: That's an antenna.

Comment: That's Antenna :v

Comment: what it is used for?
i never seen those before on any electric pole

Comment: *what it is used for?* transmission of radio waves.

Comment: @Andyaka Or reception of radio waves!

Comment: For what it's worth [here's](https://i.redd.it/11390bsvoz611.jpg)  one that isn't broken, also apparently in Israel.

Answer (score 7):

It's a folded dipole antenna originally operating somewhere near the top of of the VHF band.

It's damaged, and probably not working correctly any more.

It's for whatever is on the other end of the thin black cable.

Often theses antennae are connected to monitoring equipment and transmit data so that those in the control centre can know the state of the network.

Comment: SCADA = System Control and Data Acquisition is one name for it.